# Angular10 with BigQuery , Getting Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, angular10

I am integrating Angular10, Firebase with BigQuery using '@google-cloud/bigquery'.
I have created a function folder in my my project and in that I have added key json file which I got after generating Service account json on Google Cloud Console.

I have 2 datasets in my BigQuery dashboard whose source is Google Drive.But when I am trying to query these table I am getting error.

In my function folder I have index.js file where I am initializing my BigQuery client using following:

```js
const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({
    keyFilename:'./<name of key Json file from servie account>',
    scopes:['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    projectId:<Project-id>
  });
```

Error I am getting:
"Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials."

Also if I remove projectId while initializing my big query client, following error is logged on console:

Sorry, we cannot connect to Cloud Services without a project\n ID. You may specify one with an environment variable named\n "GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to define your scope in BigQueryClient file which exist in on below path in bigquery library structure  `application/libraries/bigqueryclient/vendor/google/cloud-bigquery/src/BigQueryClient` path.

Make the changes below

```
    const SCOPE=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',];
        const INSERT_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata';

 

    public function __construct(array $config = [])
        {
            $this->location = $this->pluck('location', $config, false);
            $this->setHttpRetryCodes([502]);
            $this->setHttpRetryMessages([
                'rateLimitExceeded',
                'backendError'
            ]);
            $config += [
                'scopes' => self::SCOPE,
                'projectIdRequired' => true,
                'returnInt64AsObject' => false,
                'restRetryFunction' => $this->getRetryFunction(),
                //@codeCoverageIgnoreStart
                'restCalcDelayFunction' => function ($attempt) {
                    return min(
                        mt_rand(0, 1000000) + (pow(2, $attempt) * 1000000),
                        self::MAX_DELAY_MICROSECONDS
                    );
                }
                //@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
            ];
            $this->connection = new Rest($this->configureAuthentication($config));
            $this->mapper = new ValueMapper($config['returnInt64AsObject']);
        }
```